# Fill spinner with array List

Tags: android

I want to fill a spinner with the items of an array List but I can´t. Here is my code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(id_circuito);
```

First, I add an element to the list and later:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
```

It says me "The constructor ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.GetContacts, int, List) is undefined", how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainActivity.GetContacts` is not a valid `Context`.

Change this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
```

OR

If its in a Fragment use `getActivity()`. Likely `GeContacts` (Fragment) is inside `MainActivity`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is related to the first argument `this` refers to `MainActivity.GetContacts`. You need a `Context` object. If you are inside a `Fragment` you can se `getActivity()`, `NomeOfYourActvity`.this otherwise